# iOS: CLLocationManager altitude returns only Integers

Tags: ios, iphone, ios9, cllocationmanager, iphone-4

Im trying to get the altitude of the CLLocationManager in iOS 9.3.2.

```
self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];

self.locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
[self.locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
[self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
```

A simple

```
NSLog(@"location Manager altitude: %.6f", self.locationManager.location.altitude);
```

returns exact values when running it on an iPhone 5S `340.234567`, but on an iPhone 4S, I get only Integer Values: `340.000000`.

I implemented the delegates `didUpdateLocations` and `didFailWithError`

I tried it with Wi-fi or mobile Data enabled, no difference.
Any Ideas?

Comment: I guess the GPS chipset on the 4s is different to that on later models. Vertical accuracy is probably only +/- 10m anyway